# Configuration of the maven jetty (version 8.1) plugin for jax-ws webservices

Tags: maven, jetty, jax-ws

I've managed to configure the maven jetty plugin to successfully deploy a jax-ws war with spring and an assortment of other libraries. However despite the successful deployment I'm always obtaining `HTTP ERROR 404 Problem accessing /tstsrv Reason: not found`.

The relevant section of my POM file bellow. I've commented a lot of configurations bellow that I have tried without success namely the jetty-jaxws2spi spi which I don't know quite how to configure it.

```
<build>
<finalName>tstsrv</finalName>

<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
      </dependency>
    <!-- dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-jaxws2spi</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.v20091125</version>
    </dependency -->    
      <dependency>  
          <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>  
          <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>    
          <version>2.2.6</version>
      </dependency>               
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <war>${basedir}/target/tstsrv.war<!-- ${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.${project.packaging}--></war>
      <webApp>
        <extraClasspath>${basedir}/src/main/custom/.</extraClasspath>
        <contextPath>/tstsrv</contextPath>
        <jettyEnvXml>${basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-env.xml</jettyEnvXml>            
      </webApp>

      <!-- systemProperties>
        <systemProperty>
          <name>com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider</name>
          <value>org.eclipse.jetty.jaxws2spi.JettyHttpServerProvider</value>         
        </systemProperty>
      </systemProperties -->

      <connectors>
        <connector implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
          <port>9090</port>
          <maxIdleTime>60000</maxIdleTime>
        </connector>
      </connectors>        

      <loginServices>
        <loginService implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
          <name>myrealm</name>
          <config>${basedir}/src/test/resources/jetty-realm.properties</config>
        </loginService>
      </loginServices>    

     <requestLog implementation="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
        <filename>target/tmp/yyyy_mm_dd.request.log</filename>
        <retainDays>90</retainDays>
        <append>true</append>
        <extended>false</extended>
        <logTimeZone>GMT</logTimeZone>         
     </requestLog>   
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

My Spring configuration is not using `com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet`. I'm extending `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport`. I think this is relevant because I was able to make this work but only with the `WSSpringServlet`. I've used an example in [this blog](http://blog.ippon.fr/2010/02/18/web-service-code-first-avec-jax-ws/) and that worked.
However that solution is not a option since I'm using weblogic in production and this implies code changes

Thnks for any help.

Comment: Well, if your context path is `/tstsrv`, why do you request for `/ws/tstsrv`?

Comment: My bad. That was a thypo :-( I've changed the name of the real application for privacy and failed the substitution. I've added additional details

Comment: I think you need to publish your `web.xml` as it is not clear who is serving the request. The way you use `SpringBeanAutowiringSupport` is also not clear: `WSSpringServlet` should work under weblogic (and any other Web container).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by making different configurations controlled by maven profiles. One with a WSSpringServlet for testing and the original one without it.

Tnks to commenters for the time taken to respond to this issue.

Comment: Hello, may I know what's your latest solution details now :)